# The difference between 5 times a number and 8 is equal 7 times the sum of the number and 3. Find the number.

Tags: arithmetic

The difference between 5 times a number and 8 is equal 7 times the sum of 
the number and 3. Find the number.

Answer (score 1):

Call the number $x$ and translate the sentence to an equation.

For example:

*The sum of two times the number and 4 is 0*

is the same as $2x+4=0$.

(This has nothing to do with differential geometry. It's elementary algebra from school, grade 6 or so...)

Answer (score 0):

> The difference between

This indicates a minus sign.

> 5 times a number

Call your number $x$, and multiply it by $5$ (i.e., $5x$).

> and 8

This expression so far is $5x-8$.

> is equal [to]

Put your equals sign here.

> 7 times the sum of the number and 3.

You're multiplying "the sum of the number and $3$" by $7$, so you need parentheses. Sum indicates a plus sign: $7(x+3)$.

> Find the number.

So you have $5x-8=7(x+3)$ and want to solve for $x$.

Hope this helps.